# Unable to perform login validation using angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi here I created a login page where if the response is ok then it has to login other wise it has to display error. Below is my json data here I have to provide email and password correctly :

```
{ 
  Email": "maxwil@ecoweb.com",
  password:56897

}
```

below is my  login method:

```
 this.serv.getLogin(data.Email,data.password).subscribe(res=>{
          if (res.Data.Id === 0 && res.Data.Id === null || res.Status === 'false') {
            alert('please check the username or password');
            return false;
          } else {
            console.log(res);
            localStorage.setItem('UserDetails', JSON.stringify(res));
            this.router.navigate(['/TrackDriver']);
            return true;
          }

        },err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
```

here the problem is even though I provide incorrect username and password also it is loggin in.
If I login correctly using above  mail id and password

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Email": "maxwil@ecoweb.com",
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Admin"
    },
    "ErrorCode": "201 - Success",
    "Message": "Success",
    "Status": true
}
```

if provide incorrect details also it is loggin in and getting this response

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Email": null,
    "Id": null,
    "Name": null
  },
  "ErrorCode": "501 - No Data Found",
  "Message": "Please Check Credentials",
  "Status": false
}
```

even though I provide details it is loggin in I don't what is the issue

Comment: They key/value pairs should be quoted in the login json file... `{
 "Email": "maxwil @ecoweb.com ",
 "password": "56897"
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `if` statement in the `getLogin` callback:

```
if (res.Data.Id === 0 && res.Data.Id === null || res.Status === 'false') {
```

This statement can never be true, because `res.Data.Id` can't be `0` and `null` at the same time and the types of `res.Status` aren't matching: `false` (boolean) in the actual result and `'false'` (string) in your statement.

Change the second part of the statement to check for the `res.Status` to be false:

```
if ([...] || !res.Status)
```

If `0` and `null` are both a sign of failure for the login, change the first part of the statement:

```
if (res.Data.Id === 0 && res.Data.Id === null || [...])
```

Since `0` and `null` are both `falsy` values, you can simplify this statement to the following:

```
if (!res.Data.Id || !res.Status)
```

Comment: so whats the change ?

Comment: @TechieBoy Edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The error is here :

```
res.Status === 'false'
```

You want a boolean, not a string :

```
res.Status === false // equivalent to !res.Status
```

So this will fail the login validation :

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Email": null,
    "Id": null,
    "Name": null
  },
  "ErrorCode": "501 - No Data Found",
  "Message": "Please Check Credentials",
  "Status": false // <---- Boolean!
}
```

Besides, your `if` logic is flawed. `res.Data.Id === 0 && res.Data.Id === null` this condition will never be met, a variable can't be `0` and `null` at the same time.

Comment: Thile So How can i rectify it ?